# Отображение web страницы в окне phpstorm

Tags: вёрстка, phpstorm, jetbrains

Можно ли при верстке/редактировании html страницы отображать ее в одном окне с phpstrom в режиме реальных изменений?
Очень утомляет постоянно переключатся на окно браузера(а если открыта документация то еще переключатся между вкладками) и нажимать f5

Comment: https://www.browsersync.io/ , http://livereload.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, такой возможности нет, т.к. в PHPStorm нет встроенного браузера для интерпретации HTML. чтобы не нажимать F5, можно попробовать использовать live edit - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Edit+in+PhpStorm